# How to get automatically token for dfa every 7 days

Tags: python, replace, token, report, dfa

I have DFA accounts.
I have about 1100 profiles and accounts
I can't use the service account
So, I am using the token that expired after seven days.
I replaced the token every week by myself.
My Python code opens the web browser when the token expires, and it downloads the new one but needs to approve and choose options to download.
Can I do it automatically, and my token will be replaced automatically and not manually?
Is there any Python code that can do it?
Can I get Token for a long time without a service account?
Thanks

I wrote above all the options I tried.

Comment: You tagged this with `dfa`. So what is a Deterministic Finite Automaton *account*? I guess you are talking about another concept having the same acronym, and have used the wrong tag -- drawing the wrong experts to your question.